# My code doesn't work when I have more then two objects in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm new in React.js and I need some help when I pick up objects from the database.
I have an API to fetch data from my MySQL database and when I have more then two objects with `sportid='26'` in the database I got this:

> "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input".

If it's one or two objects it works perfectly.

Someone who can tell me why?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Popup from './Popup';

class Riding extends Component {
        
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: null,
          clicked: false,
          open: false,
        };
        this.togglePopup = this.togglePopup.bind(this);
    }

    togglePopup() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            clicked: true
        }));
    }
    
    
           
    componentDidMount() {

        let data = fetch('http://localhost/reusesport/src/api/riding.php')
            .then((res) => {
                res.json().then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.setState({data:res})
                })
            })
    
            
    }
         
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="Advertisment_title">Ridsport</h1>
            <div className="Advertisment">
              {
                    this.state.data ?
                    this.state.data.map((item) =>
                    <div className="AdvertismentBox"  onClick={this.togglePopup}>
                     {this.state.clicked ? <Popup id={item.id} title={item.title} text={item.text} date={item.date} price={item.price} municipality={item.municipality} county={item.county}/> : null}
                    <h3 className="AdvertismentBox_title">{item.title}</h3>
                    <img src={item.picture} alt={item.title}/>
                    <h3 className="AdvertismentBox_price">{item.price}</h3>
                    <h3 className="AdvertismentBox_date">{item.date}</h3>
                    <h3 className="AdvertismentBox_county">{item.county}</h3>
                    </div>
                )
                    :
                    <h3>Vänta - datat hämtas</h3>
                }
            </div>    
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Riding;
```

My API:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-Type:application/json");

include("connect.php");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `advertisment` WHERE sportid='26'";
       
$result = $connect ->query($sql);
$return_arr = array();

if($result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
        $row_array['picture'] = $row['picture'];
        $row_array['price'] = $row['price'];
        $row_array['date'] = $row['date'];
        $row_array['county'] = $row['county'];
            array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    }
}    
mysqli_close($connect);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Comment: can you add some JSON with more than 2 objects in it so that we can debug that also?

Comment: Which line exactly throws that error? And please show us what JSON is produced by `echo json_encode($return_arr);` in the case where there are more than 2 objects.

Comment: Line 27 in the js-file gives the error. 
The echo json_encode($return_arr); gives nothing as I can see.

Comment: you can try commenting the code with issue
> res.json().then((res) => { ... }) and just try to do console.log(res)
> .then((res) => { console.log(res)}) now inspect the value returned by res, if that is valid JSON or not.
if not, debug your api :)

Comment: if that returns nothing, then perhaps there's a problem with the conversion. Add some debugging - add `var_dump($return_arr);` before the json_encode to check the contents of the raw array. And after the json_encode, add `echo json_last_error_msg();` to see if the JSON encoding failed for some reason. (N.B. although adding these lines will crash your JS (due to none of it being valid JSON), you'll be able to see the output of the PHP in the Response to your AJAX call, using your browser's developer tools)

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>    string(2) "14"
    ["title"]=>    string(5) "Sadel"
    ["picture"]=>    string(24) "./../images/14/sadel.jpg"
    ["price"]=>    string(4) "2000"
    ["date"]=>    string(10) "2018-03-19"
    ["county"]=>    string(10) "Norrbotten"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>    string(2) "18"
    ["title"]=>    string(10) "Ridstovlar"
    ["picture"]=>    string(30) "./../images/18/ridstovlar.jpg "
    ["price"]=>    string(3) "300"
    ["date"]=>    string(10) "2019-01-08"
    ["county"]=>    string(10) "Norrbotten"
  }
}

Comment: When I have more then 3 objects in the database. 

[{"id":"3","title":"konstakningsdrakt","picture":"\"..\/images\/3\/drakt.JPG\" ","price":"300","date":"2018-04-18"},{"id":"5","title":"konstakningsskridsko storlek 38","picture":"\"..\/images\/5\/konstakningsskridskor.jpg\" ","price":"2000","date":"2018-04-19"},{"id":"10","title":"Skridskor","picture":"<img src=\"..\/images\/3\/hockeyskridskor.jpg\" alt=\"skridskor\">","price":"140","date":"2018-09-04"}]

Comment: The swedish Å,Ä and ö was the problem. Now it´s work.